# Add a question per checked multiple choice answer

Tags: google-forms

Say I have the following question:

```
What are your favorite things (multiple choice)?
[ ] Thing A
[x] Thing B
[ ] Thing C
[x] Thing D
```

I'd like to dynamically generate the following sections with several questions in them:

```
Questions about Thing B:
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
```

```
Questions about Thing D:
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
```

I think "Sections based on answers" cannot be used for multiple choice? And even if it's possible it would mean I'd have to duplicate the sections, which makes it hard to maintain. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> I think "Sections based on answers" cannot be used for multiple choice?

You are right.

NOTE: Google Apps Script could be helpful to make reduce the burden of maintaining a form.